# Shortcut for nautilus

Tags: nautilus, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I would like to use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> as a shortcut to open Nautilus. Whenever I add <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> as a shortcut in *System Settings* > *Keyboard* > *Shortcuts* it works fine. But after I reboot/re-log <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> does not work anymore. On the other hand, the shortcut is still correctly listed in *Keyboard* > *Shortcuts*.

I've already tried **CompizConfig Manager** and configured a new command for starting Nautilus, but this seems to be buggy: Nautilus will always open behind the current active window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. System settings -▸ Keyboard -▸
2. Launchers | Home folder
3. Press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and close the dialogs.
4. Now press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and it should open the `/Home`folder in nautilus.

It worked for me.